# How do you change the border color of a word in keybindings.json in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been doing customization lately, but one problem I've found is that I can't customize some features

How do you change the border color of a word in keybindings.json in vscode?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtVHb.png)

my settings..

```
        "editorError.border": "#E06c75",
        "editorError.foreground": "#E06c75",
        "editorError.background": "#E06c7580",
        "editorWarning.border": "#e5c07b",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#e5c07b",
        "editorWarning.background": "#e5c07b60",
        "editorInfo.border": "#98c379",
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#98c379",
```

Comment: I have found 1 theme with a different border color: Solarized Dark, but I can't find the color in the theme definition, it has a border but not a span tag in the DOM (Developer Tools), most likely it is a Decorator (character range with style) (I don't know where to look for decorators in the DOM), the background color changes with the theme, you can create an issue asking to explain what it is and how to change the color

Comment: @TaoTao Is that a selection you have made in the keybindings or a find result or what?

Comment: @Mark I'm using the keybinds.jsonn file to explain the problem (an example)

Comment: @TaoTao Yes, but it is important how that text got selected in the first place.  Are they find matches or what?

Comment: @Mark I tried it too and it seems a string with `[Semicolon]` as keycombo in `keybindings.json` gets special decoration, looks like all layout-independent scan codes get this decoration

Comment: @Mark Just looked at [Keyboard layouts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-layouts) and it has a screen shot of a key bindings file that decorates some key combos with a border and a background color

Comment: @rioV8 Can you actually change those though - I bet they can't be changed by the user like that, i.e., border, etc.

Comment: @Mark If the code uses a custom named color in `package.json` and uses that color in the decorator you can customize that color in `settings.json`. Now we need to find the source code where the key bindings decorators are applied

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `settings.json`

**Add** setting (change the *Theme Name* and color)

```json
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Theme Name]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        { "scope":"keyword.control",
          "settings": {"border": "1px solid #888888"}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: tips:  "Property border is not allowed."

Comment: Yes, only `foreground` and `fontStyle` are supported there.